# browser base remote desktop with thumbnail viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, websocket, html5-canvas

I would like to create a browser base VNC that can view via Browser and the VNC appears as a thumbnail.. Just like ThinVNC for example. Is it possible to create such system? how? Hoping for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed [VncSharp](http://cdot.senecac.on.ca/projects/vncsharp/) in a full-trust [XAML Browser Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx) (XBAP). It's a Windows Forms control, so you will have to put it into a [WindowsFormHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx).

Comment: Thank you Sir for your help! :) I would like to ask if what should I do first? sorry I'm a newbie for this PL. I ask some of my friends and they told me to create a TCP/IP server and client first.,,I'm confuse Sir. again Thank you Sir  :)

Comment: Sir :), VncSharp is a VNC client (also called VNC viewer), so if there is a VNC server (e.g. TightVNC or RealVNC) installed on the PC to be remote controlled, than that's enough.

Comment: First, I would download VncSharp, and try to understand the example code: it's a desktop VNC client. The code is pretty simple, you basically put a `VncSharp.RemoteDesktop` control on a form, call its `Connect` and `Disconnect` members, and check its `IsConnected` property.

Comment: Second, try to find example codes about how to create Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) applications. Learn what XAML is. Since `VncSharp.RemoteDesktop` is a Winforms control, you can add it to the GUI of a WPF application only when you put it into a `WindowsFormHost`.

Comment: Third, try to find examples about how to create the in-browser version of a WPF application, called an XBAP application. Since `VncSharp.RemoteDesktop` builds up a network connection, you will have to make your XBAP app fully trusted.

Comment: Fourth, you have to deploy your XBAP-based VNC viewer application to a web server. It can be done from Visual Studio, check out the project info page. When the user opens the URL of your VNC viewer, the browser will download it in the background, and show it embedded into the browser window.

Comment: THANK YOU SO much!Sir. you're so kind Sir, Even though all of this are not familiar to me I'll do my best to make it happen, one thing sir...this can be done only in LAN. do in need to have a multithread Server/client?. thank you again and again sir :) your the best

Comment: Sir, AFAIK the answer to your question about threading is no.

Comment: Done Sir :) Sorry I'm new to this site :) ..I'll be back to you soon for further assistance. Thanks Sir.